# $\theta''(x) \geq \rho > 0$ implies $\biggl|\int_a^be^{i\theta(x)}dx\biggr|\leq \frac{8}{\sqrt{\rho}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

This is part b) of exercise 14.4 from Steele's "The Cauchy-Schwarz Masterclass".

In part a) we prove that given $\theta:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, monotonic, and satisfies $\theta'(x)\geq \nu > 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then
$$
\biggl|\int_a^be^{i\theta(x)}dx\biggr|\leq \frac{4}{\nu}.
$$
That part is proven using the *second* MVT theorem for definite integrals.

We're then asked to use this bound in part b) and prove that given twice differentiable $\theta$ with $\theta''(x)\geq\rho>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then
$$
\biggl|\int_a^be^{i\theta(x)}dx\biggr|\leq \frac{8}{\sqrt{\rho}}.
$$

In the solution for this exercise, Steele cleverly splits the integral into smaller integrals $I_1, I_2, I_3$ over $[a,c-\delta],[c-\delta,c+\delta]$, and $[c+\delta,b]$, respectively, where $c\in[a,b]$ is a point where $\theta'(c)=0$ and $\delta > 0$. He then proceeds by using the bound for $|I_1|$ and $|I_3|$, "trivially" bounds $|I_2|\leq 2\delta$, and arrives at the desired bound by minimizing $\delta$.

My main question is how does he come to the conclusion that $\theta'(x)\geq \rho\delta$ for all $x\in[c+\delta,b]$. I'd imagine that he integrates both sides of $\theta''(x)\geq \rho$ over $[c+\delta, x]$ to get
$$
\theta'(x) - \theta'(c+\delta) \geq \rho(x-c-\delta) \implies \theta'(x) \geq \rho(x-c-\delta),
$$
since $\theta'(c+\delta)>0$, but this is obviously not the same. A similar bound is proven for the interval $[a,c-\delta]$.

Now, given how ridden with errors this book is, I wonder if I'm missing something really trivial, or if it's indeed a mistake in the solution. It's definitely not documented in the latest errata (which hasn't been updated for ages).

In any case, I also would like to know how to solve this with this and/or other methods.

My approach instead would be to find a $\delta > 0$, such that $\theta'(x) > \delta\rho$ for $x\in(c,b]$, and $\theta'(x) < -\delta\rho$ for $x\in[a,c)$, and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in [c+\delta;b]$, then we have (using $\theta'(c)=0$)
$$\theta'(x)=\theta'(c)+\int_c^x \theta''(s)ds =\int_c^x \theta''(s) ds \geq \int_c^x \rho ds =\rho (x-c).$$
However, if $x\in [c+\delta;b]$, then $x\geq c+\delta$ and thus $x-c\geq \delta$, which implies the desired bound.

Similarly one can establish the bound on the other interval.

Comment: Very nice! I'm glad it's not something "trivial" that I missed. Can you perhaps also extend your answer for the case when $\theta'$ does not vanish?

Comment: If you have no point where the function vanishes, your bounds just get better, because you are not starting from zero. Say $\theta'(a)>0$, then $\theta'(x)\geq \theta'(a)+\rho(x-a).$ Again you can split $[a;b]$, this time into $[a;a+\delta]$ and the rest and optimize again over $\delta$.

Comment: In the sense that we can find a small enough $\delta$ that satisfies $\theta'(x)\geq \delta\rho$ and we can minimize it further to get desired bound?

Comment: See my edited comment. However, I have not done the minimization, so you might want to check it. It should be fine, because the estimates just go better.

Comment: Indeed, then the bound drops down to $4/\sqrt{\rho}$, thanks!